# Initializing a Mercurial Repository from a Maven Archetype

Tags: java, maven, mercurial, maven-archetype

In order to make it simpler and easier for developers to get up and going, I've implemented a Maven Archetype that generates a project tailor-made for our environment. The Archetype works pretty well, but fails to complete the setup on one key point: The generated project lacks a Mercurial repository.

Is there any way I can run `hg init` from the Archetype?

The core reason for this request is that I want to reduce the number of steps developers have to go through when creating and configuring a new product. As many as five or more modules may need to be created, each requiring its own check-in. The modules are not intended to be grouped into EAR bundles as they may be deployed independently in the architecture.

It is acceptable for the answer to be, "no, there is no solution". This is about optimizing the zero to operational time through automation. If it can't be automated using Maven's mechanisms, then I would rather not implement a solution than find a sub-standard solution.

One solution that I have considered is using the ANT plugin to call `hg` from the command line. The part I don't like about this solution is that it relies on the user having the Mercurial executable available in the path. That's a dependency that could create a point of failure. Such a point of failure would complicate initial setup rather than simplifying it as intended. (Ergo, why "no solution" is a viable answer.)

Thank you to everyone for your suggestions so far!

Comment: How can they commit if they don't have the executable on the path? I don't see how they can't have this dependency and how it is a problem.

Comment: Well, that's a good question. Is what I'm asking for even feasible? Can Maven manage the necessary tasks internally? Or do all solutions (e.g. Maven SCM) rely on external executables being installed? A user who installs a graphical tool might be able to perform Mercurial operations through the tool without having the necessary tools on the PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not write your own Maven plugin that does the `hg init` and whatever else you need? Writing basic Maven plugins like this isn't that hard.

Personally I would [get the source for the scm plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/) and add an `init` goal to the plugin . That would be the cleanest way to do it.

Not having an `init` goal in the scm plugin looks like a glaring omission in my opinion. It might even make it back into the main code if you submit the changes.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. If it turns out that there is no plugin to achieve what I need, maybe I'll go that route. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No that i know. Is that a big deal to run after a creation the hg init manually ? Or what about putting a script into the archetype which will be called manually..this doens't change things but you can define default behaviour in it.

Comment: By itself, the step is not too arduous. However, the developer needs to create about 5 modules from these Archetypes to get a new product up and running. (There's a strong division of responsibility going on between modules.) Given the repetitive nature of these steps, I'm trying to reduce the steps taken to as few as possible. More automation is always a good thing.

Using an ANT script to make a call to the command line has occurred to me. However, I hate using such a clunky solution with Maven. I was hoping (perhaps against hope) that there might be a better plugin solution?

Comment: Might it a better idea to create a multi-module structure to reduce the number of calls to one?

Comment: Our practice (which I understand to be fairly standard) has been to have one Maven repo per module. Thus your suggestion only reduces the number of Archetypes, not the number of Mercurial repositories.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is standard (but thats not the point), cause if you have multi-module build you have everything in one HG repo (git repo)...A multi-module project summarizes different modules which result into an application (J2EE application are typical examples for them one ear, one war, one ejb ..etc.)...and your description sound exactly like this case.

Comment: I've updated the original question to clarify some of the points we've been talking about. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want each developer to create a mercurial repository using `hg init`?  What you need is for each developer to be able to start off by cloning a central `hg` repository.  This could possibly be done using the [maven scm plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/) goals like `scm:bootstrap` or `scm:checkout`.

Comment: In this case the Archetype is used to generate the first instance of the project. So there will be no central check-in when this Archetype is run. Thus the desire to create the initial repository that can be pushed to the central server.